# Laravel Changing Request data in Form Request Class

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm processing a form with multiple date input which is not in A.D. For validation purpose i'm using Form Request.

Before validation and inserting in my database date input must be converted into A.D, so that i can do the proper validation & then if validation succeed date input is stored in A.D .

here is my code for converting date input in A.D

```
<?php

abstract class Request extends FormRequest
{
    public function all()
    {

       $input = parent::all()

       foreach ($input as $key=>$value)
       {
            if (substr($key, -5) == "_date")
            {
                $input[$key] = Helper::convert_in_ad($value);
            }
       }
       return $input;
    }
}
```

Now the problem is suppose you have failed validation and redirect back to the previous action and you then use old() or some other method to access the request data from the session, it will be modified, and i cannot get the the original data.

How can i change the date input in A.D when before validation so that i can properly validate in A.D and then store all the date input in A.D. by solving failed validation problem having modified input.

### Edit Question

update:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use App\Repositories\Contracts\CourseInterface;
use App\Repositories\Contracts\ClassInterface;


use App\Http\Requests\ClassRequest;
use App\Helpers\Helper;

class ClassController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct(ClassInterface $class, CourseInterface $course)
    {
        $this->class = $class;
        $this->course = $course;
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $classes = $this->class->paginate();

        return view('backend.class.index')->with([
            'classes' => $classes
        ]);

        /*return view('backend.class.index')->with([
            'classes' => $classes
        ]);*/
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $courses = $this->course->all();

        return view('backend.class.create')->with([
            'courses' => $courses
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(ClassRequest $request)
    {

      //  dd($request->all());

        $this->class->create($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('classes.index');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $class = $this->class->find($id);
        $courses = $this->course->all();

        return view('backend.class.edit')->with([
            'class' => $class,
            'courses' => $courses
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(ClassRequest $request, $id)
    {
        $class = $this->class->update($request->all(), $id);

        return redirect()->back();
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $this->class->delete($id);

        return redirect()->route('classes.index');
    }

    public function delete($id)
    {
        $class = $this->class->find($id);

        return view('backend.class.delete')->with([
            'class' => $class
        ]);
    }
}
```

### My class Request File

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;
use App\Helpers\Helper;

class ClassRequest extends Request
{

public function all()
{
    $input = parent::all();

    foreach ($input as $key=>$value)
    {
        if (substr($key, -5) == "_date")
        {
            $input[$key] = Helper::convert_in_ad($value);
        }
    }
    return $input;
}

/**
 * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{

    //$this->sanitize();

    switch($this->method())
    {
        case 'GET':
        case 'DELETE':
        {
            return [];
        }
        case 'POST':
        {
            return [
                'name'          => 'required',
                'course_id'     => 'required',
                'start_date'    => 'required|date',
                'end_date'      => 'date|after:start_date',
            ];
        }
        case 'PUT':
        case 'PATCH':
        {
            return [
                'name'          => 'required',
                'course_id'     => 'required',
                'start_date'    => 'required|date',
                'end_date'      => 'date|after:start_date',
            ];
        }
        default:break;
    }
}

}
```

For validation purpose i need to change the date from B.S in A.D because laraval validation don't recognize B.S date. If i convert date in request file the problem is if validation fails i get the modified request back in form after redirect.

So how can i validate the date by converting it into A.D. The date in database table must be stored in A.D format for that i can use Accessors and Mutators the main problem is how to validate the data which user input in B.S format.

### Edit After the suggestion i got

Thank you all for the suggestion, thank you very much for your help. One way i can validate is by making a custom validation rule as suggested. Right now i have another idea for making this work.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use App\Helpers\Helper;

abstract class Request extends FormRequest
{
/**
 * Sanitize input before validation
 * 
 * @return array
 */
public function validator($factory)
{
    return $factory->make(
        $this->sanitizeInput(), $this->container->call([$this, 'rules']), $this->messages()
    );
}

protected function sanitizeInput()
{
    if (method_exists($this, 'sanitize'))
    {
        return $this->container->call([$this, 'sanitize']);
    }

    return $this->all();
}

/**
 * Check for input having _date for converting it into AD
 * 
 * @return array
 */

public function sanitize()
{
    $input = $this->all();

    foreach ($input as $key=>$value)
    {
        if (substr($key, -5) == "_date")
        {
            $input[$key] = Helper::convert_in_ad($value);
        }
    }

    return $input;
}


}
```

By using the following code request data is not changed. And There will be no need for creating custom validation and this will be easy if i later decided to take date in A.D from user then changing every request file for updating validation rule wont be necessary.

What do you think about this?

Comment: what is A.D. in here?

Comment: A.D is a Date in our country we use Date format which is Not in A.D

Comment: show your controller codes I can help

Comment: public function store(ClassRequest $request)
    {


        $this->class->create($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('classes.index');
    }

Comment: Don't modify the original data/fields, instead add new fields.

Comment: My form contain the date in Bikram Sambat When i submit the form all the input provided will be validated using Form Request. so date in Bikram Sambat must be converted in AD during validation. I have to store all the date in A.D after passing validation. I'm using mass assignment for storing data using model. so the problem is if i change the date in AD from BS in form request when validation fails and redirect back is occured form gets the converted value.

Comment: I want the controller code not the modified request codes

Comment: I have updated my question with the controller and form request code. Please check it

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned in the comments you should try and avoid editing the data in your `FormRequest`.

What you could do is define a new validation rule specifically for this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#custom-validation-rules

So, in your `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider` (or another registered `ServiceProvider`) you could have something like:

```
Validator::extend('bs_date', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {

    $date = date_parse(Helper::convert_in_ad($value));

    return checkdate($date['month'], $date['day'], $date['year']);
}, 'Your error message');

Validator::extend('bs_after', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {

    $data = $validator->getData();

    $before = Helper::convert_in_ad($data[$parameters['0']]);

    $after = Helper::convert_in_ad($value);

    return (new \DateTime($before)) < (new \DateTime($after));
}, 'Your error message');
```

Rules

```
'start_date'    => 'required|bs_date',
'end_date'      => 'date|bs_after:start_date',
```

Obviously, don't forget to import `Validator` and `Helper` in the `ServiceProvider`.

This should mean that you don't have to edit your input anymore.

Hope this helps!